# Send ViewModel to API ASP.net Core 2

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

i'm working in a project Core 2.2
API Project for Db Layer
Web Project For Views

I can Read Data from API
But I have A problem sending data for update

Code

1- Send Data From Web Project

```
 [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(NationalityViewModel nationality )
    {
        LawyerAPI lawyerAPI = new LawyerAPI();
        HttpClient httpClient = lawyerAPI.InitializeClient();            
       HttpResponseMessage res = await httpClient.PutAsJsonAsync("api/nofactory/updatenationality", nationality);       
        return View(nationality);
     
    }
```

2-InitializeClient

```
 private string _apiBaseURI = "http://localhost:57030";
    public HttpClient InitializeClient()
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        //Passing service base url  
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(_apiBaseURI);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
        //Define request data format  
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        return client;

    }
```

3- API

```
  [Route("updatenationality")]
   
    public IActionResult Put(NationalityViewModel nationality)
    { 

        var nat=new Nationality();
        nat.Name=nationality.Name;
        nat.IsActive=nationality.IsActive;
        nat.Id=nationality.Id;
             _NationalityRepository.Update(nat);
       
        return Ok();
    }
```

the problem is that the nationality variable in the Web Project has data and when sent to the API it is empty model the break point hit the API method but the variable is empty

I think the problem is the send function.

For Clarification I added images:

[image: Web Controller Data]

[image: Api Controller]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to tell the framework to bind from request body. You do it by annotating your `NationalityViewModel` parameter with `[FromBody]` attribute.

`public IActionResult Put([FromBody] NationalityViewModel nationality)`

Comment: Thank you that was so simple